# send push notification to android app using php without external cloud like firebase

Tags: android-studio, android-intent, push-notification, android-notifications, localnotification

I hope help me to fund a good tutorial for send push notification to android app using php without external cloud like firebase , just php in my localhost to Android app

If yes, how can I do it?

Comment: You couldn't push notification without using cloud service, but you can request for some data from a server and get response without using cloud service

Comment: If you wish to do it, just leave a comment

Comment: Ok my friend can I send notification from my web to android ..

Comment: No, but you can request for some data and get response

Comment: Ok how can I do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You couldn't push notification without using cloud service, but you can request for some data from a server and get a response without using cloud service. You can use network libray like `volley` and `retrofit`. Here I shows an example of volley

Add the following dependency in your app gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
}
```

Add internet permission in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

And add the following in your activity

```
//specify url
String url = "https:yourIpAddress/file.php";

// make a request
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
        url, null,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                //Success
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                //Error
            }
        });

//Make a request queue
RequestQueue mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

//Add request to requestQueue
mRequestQueue.add(jsonObjReq);
```

For more details refer [enter link description here](https://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/)

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: If it is useful for you, then please upvote my answer